# Will Ubuntu 20.04LTS boot a computer configured for UEFI secure boot?

Tags: 20.04, lts, secure-boot

I have a home-built PC with Gigabyte H370N-WIFI motherboard and two SSDs (the primary one with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and another one for gaming running Windows 10).  I want to be sure my PC will support Windows 11 in the future.  When I run Windows health check to check compatibility with Windows 11, it tells me I need to enable UEFI secure boot.
My question is - if I were to enable secure boot in BIOS would this affect my ability to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Turn on secure boot, upgrade and then turn off secure boot after.

Comment: It might. The doc from microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-secure-boot  could include non-windows partition as "untrusted". If they want the could enforce a full recovery deleting any non-windows partition.

Comment: A lot of things like video drivers and virtual box will stop working if you enable secure boot assuming you haven't done the signing key thing.

Comment: All good information to have.  Thanks for cluing me in.

Comment: @Rinzwind I wouldn't put it past Microsoft to change/delete Linux ext4 partitions... like they did with major Windows updates and MBR disks on single disk installations.

Answer (score 3):

I am using dual-boot system with windows 10 and kubuntu 21.04 (earlier ubuntu 20.04). I have enabled secure boot ON. Not facing any issues in booting either of the OS. I have one single SSD.