# Bootable USB does not boot

Tags: 22.04, rufus

I used Rufus to add the ISO file for Ubuntu 22.04 with the defaults loaded. Every time I boot to install Ubuntu, I get stuck with a screen showing HP and Ubuntu are loading, but it never starts:

Boot options configuration:

Legacy support: enabled
Secure boot: disabled
UEFI boot order: USB diskette on key/USB Hard Disk is the first option

Update: the black screen I get after choosing the "Try or install Ubuntu" option:

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot may help.

Comment: And do the smart thing: Disable Legacy/CSM. The year is 2022, not 2011.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Ubuntu 20.04LTS boot a computer configured for UEFI secure boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367754/will-ubuntu-20-04lts-boot-a-computer-configured-for-uefi-secure-boot)

Comment: @karel 
i do not think it is related to any of the BIOS options, I tried all possible options available. i added a picture of the message I get after I choose "install or try ubuntu" option - please have a look at the post again

Comment: "Windows is hibernated" indicates you need to go to the power options, hidden options, advanced options,... dig around a bit, and turn off hibernation's "fast startup".

Comment: @ubfan1
it is actually  turned off and i do not have it listed in the power button..
I honestly do not know what is the error is coming from!